# How the product edit form generated in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product

Suppose I'm talking about downloadable product.

How the product edit form generated which default files will work for it in magento2?

Can you please help me if you know?

Answer (score 2):

Product edit page generated using UI component modifier feature. [More detail here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html).

For downloadable product, if you open **vendor/magento/module-downloadable/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** and check following code:

```
<type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="downloadablePanel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DownloadablePanel</item>
            <item name="links" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links</item>
            <item name="samples" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Samples</item>
            <item name="usedDefault" xsi:type="string">Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\UsedDefault</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Now you have all class that created Ui component form extra field for downloadable product.

Comment: thanks Sohel Rana 

Can you please help me more that how data pass to html from the downloadablepanel and display all the html and js path also if you can explain

Comment: Check how ui component work, then you will understand this things. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html